# Wireless QCA9377 not working at 16.04

Tags: 16.04, wireless, atheros

I'm not able to see my wifi device on my Lenovo Y520 notebook running Kubuntu 16.04 LTS. Even though it's not running, command `ip link show` shows that I have only `lo`, `enp4s0`, and `wlp3s0`. I tried to do `sudo ifup wlp3s0` but it says "Unknown interface wlp3s0"

But, I've confirmed that the device works fine on PuppyLinux based on Xenial, which is funny. In Puppy, the device name is wlan0.

I did some comparison on the following command `modinfo ath10k_pci` on both OSes and the diff is only:

```
ichsan@future:~$ diff /tmp/ubuntu  /tmp/puppy 
1c1
< filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.0-28-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k/ath10k_pci.ko
---
> filename: /lib/modules/4.9.58/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k/ath10k_pci.ko
24d23
< srcversion:     50E531406EF702B9976A8A9
32a32,33
> alias:          of:N*T*Cqcom,ipq4019-wifiC*
> alias:          of:N*T*Cqcom,ipq4019-wifi
35c36
< vermagic:       4.10.0-28-generic SMP mod_unload 
---
> vermagic:       4.9.58 SMP preempt mod_unload modversions
```

This is my wireless card details retrieved from my Ubuntu https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/mpDvkd4WZc/

This one is from my Puppy https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/ZFpm8NW5Hm/

Comment: Are there any differences between /etc/modprobe.d/ directories of the 2 OS's?

Comment: You want me to compare filenames inside recursively? Or want me to compare the file size as well?

Comment: Just compare the contents of the files in that location, I suspect you might see `blacklist ideapad_laptop` on Puppy Linux

Comment: Checked on Puppy, it's not blacklisted

Answer (score 0):

Suddenly it works. It seems that we just need to upgrade all packages with apt then restart. The device name will remain the same (not changed to wlan0)